# Space in node script interpreter path (windows)

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to make a node package that I can run from the console anywhere I wish, but I am having trouble specifying the script interpreter.

I have this:
`#!/c/Program Files/nodejs/node`

The problem is the space. I've tried with both `''` and `""` around the path, but it doesn't seem to help.

Does anyone know how I can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Escape the space: `#!/c/Program\ Files/nodejs/node`